# iOS UITextField in UIScrollView not responding

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uitextfield

- I have a ScrollView (coming from a xib file), which works as expected.
- Inside my ScrollView i have a UIView (a little bit smaller than the scroll view). The UIView has userInteractionEnabled = YES
- Inside my UIView is a UITextField which is centered in the middle of the UIView.

The textField only responds to touches when the frame of the textfield is on the top of the UIView. For example when i set the frame to (0,0,280,100) the textfield responds. But with a frame (0,100,280,100) it doesn't work.

The TextField has a height of 100. But it responds only in the upper part of the textField.

Here is the code "not working" (Developing on iOS 7 beta 5). Thanks for help!

```
page1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(5, 5, scrollView.frame.size.width-10,self.scrollView.frame.size.height-10)];

userNameInput = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(6, 6, 280, 100)];
[userNameInput setCenter:CGPointMake(page1.frame.size.width / 2, page1.frame.size.height / 2.5f)];
[userNameInput setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[userNameInput setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

userNameInput.enabled = YES;
userNameInput.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
userNameInput.placeholder = @"Enter...";
userNameInput.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
userNameInput.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
userNameInput.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
userNameInput.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
userNameInput.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
userNameInput.font = [SystemUtils getSystemFontWithTextSize:30.0f];
userNameInput.delegate = self;
userNameInput.tag = 1;

page1.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[page1 addSubview:userNameInput];

[userNameInput setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
[page1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

[self.scrollView addSubview:page1];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the scroll view what its content size is (presumably, in this case, you want it to be the same as page1 UIView):

```
[self.scrollView setContentSize:page1.bounds.size];
[self.scrollView addSubview:page1];
```

Comment: I assume this code is from within your `UIViewController`? Which method is this taken from? Your allocation of the `page1` object might be getting set to a frame size you are expecting (ie width and height are 0.0)

Comment: Yes right! The code is in the "viewDidLoad" from my view controller. I think the frame size is correct. I set the background color for each element (UIScrollView, UIView and UITextField) Seems like everything fits. Also no overlapping. Every rect is inside another rect.

Comment: Well, you have **something** overlapping, or clipping, and is causing the touches to not be received by the UITextField object. However, I see you have set the background colors to help visually confirm that, and you say you don't see anything. What about the views further up the hierarchy that contains your UIScrollView (or is your `UIScrollView` the root view of the view controller)? Did you check that those are the expected sizes?

Comment: Based on what little information you gave (ie code is in `viewDidLoad` and this project was presumably(?) created with Xcode 5 Beta 5, which means you are using Storyboards, etc), I created a project from scratch and pasted your code in, and it worked fine. So, I suggest showing more of your class code relevant to this problem and providing more details to help us help you.